# Trying to upload a AnyLogic model to AnyLogic Cloud that uses an AI Brain developed in Bonsai

Tags: anylogic

As personal training for working with the Bonsai platform, I've used a model called "Activity Based Cost Analysis" and developed a Brain using Bonsai to optimize the models performance.

The brain has been fully trained and exported into an Azure Web App. Locally it worked well but when I upload the model to AnyLogic cloud I get the following error message:

[image: Error visualize in console when trying to run the uploaded model in Anylogic Cloud]

This is how the Bonsai Connector block properties look in AnyLogic:
[image: Bonsai Connector block properties]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The AnyLogic public cloud prohibits any access to the Web, so this will not work.